# What can I do to re-open this closed as duplicate question, because it is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion

About [How to make a sub-domain an alias of other domain when a wilcard exist to that level in the dns server](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33178/all-my-subdomains-points-to-the-same-directory) which is closed as exact duplicate of [vhost set up help -- domain and ip point to the same site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33093/vhost-set-up-help-domain-and-ip-point-to-the-same-site)

I'm the one that answered the question in linux.stackexchange.com.  Now I noticed it was migrated here, but was closed by a moderator (and not by the cummunity) as exact duplicate.  It looks like [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) made his decission **based on the title of the question**, and not on the actual content, and *the actual question* indeed.

What the question need is someone who can edit it and change the title.  Or maybe it is a duplicate, but not of the pointed question.

I'm new here so I do not have enough reputation to vote it to reopen.

The questioner looks new to all the StackExchange eco-system, so s/he is pointless and just post a comment about her closed question.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are identical questions. You would treat an IP as an actual Host name in Apache, so using the `VirtualHost` container, `ServerName 10.0.1.12` and `ServerName 10.0.1.13` are both treated like `ServerName www.example.com` or `ServerName sub2.example.com` and could all host different content.

The way Apache treats all unknown hosts (if someone points `www.example2.com` to your server and you DO NOT host it), is that it will look for the VERY FIRST `VirtualHost` in your configuration, and use that as the default.

A **configuration error** will cause Apache to in fact not realize it has multiple `VirtualHost` blocks, and use the first one as a catch-all for all domains even if you try to host them.

Comment: The question is not about Apache, did you read it?